# Reuse Many to Many Table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Greetings i have following Models:

```
public class Product 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
}


public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}


public class Language 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

Language has many to many relation to Product And also Category. the traditional way is you create `Language_Product` Table and `Language_Category` table but I was wondering if it's possible to create a single table so I won't make duplicate Many-to-Many tables for other models that have many to many relation with my Language. something like below (keep in mind their IDs are same datatype):

```
LanguageId                             GroupId     
-------                                ----     
a2b4a2d1255540aeb6c41e4309e14a80       4cf16dd0baa9424e89f7bb43deefd0cc <-- Product
95870ac828c84937baab63ad39b4f420       4cf16dd0baa9424e89f7bb43deefd0cc <-- Product
95870ac828c84937baab63ad39b4f420       55c884375d304f958fa6b4dde1d29559 <-- Category
...
```

Also if it's possible then Does EF understand the relation and will i be able to get the data same way i used to create many-to-many relations as before in code-first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have a single table for the many-to-many relationship - that will break your db model, and you won't be able to implement data integrity properly, i.e. you won't be able to use foreign keys.

Better, have a single table for the data like categories and titles, and add a column to know which record which type is.  Then, you will have also a single many-to-many table.